# Android Room - concurrent queries performance

Tags: android, android-room

I'm having trouble with the performance of Room Database.

I need to execute concurrent queries to the same table, like the code below. I noticed the times of these queries increasing gradually, as if they were dependent on each other.

```
s = System.currentTimeMillis()
invoiceIds.map {
    async {
        val t = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val invoice = invoiceDao.findById(it.webId)
        Log.d(TAG, "${System.currentTimeMillis() - t} ms")
        invoice
    }
}.awaitAll()
Log.d(TAG, "Total ${System.currentTimeMillis() - s} ms")
```

What is the cause and is there a way to fix it?

Thanks in advance!